# xgb hyper parameter tuning using random search cv

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, random-forest

```py
cross_val = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=split_number)

index_iterator = cross_val.split(features_dataframe, classes_dataframe)

clf = RandomForestClassifier()

random_grid = _create_hyperparameter_finetuning_grid()

clf_random = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = clf, param_distributions = random_grid, n_iter = 100, cv = cross_val,verbose=2, random_state=42, n_jobs = -1)

clf_random.fit(X, y)
```

i found this code for random search cv  on some site . iam not sure what "random_grid = _create_hyperparameter_finetuning_grid() " in the code .
please enlighten me on this .

hyper parameter tuning

Answer (score 0):

It is passed as the second parameter to the model, and in the documentation (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) it's reported that it should be a "Dictionary with parameters names (str) as keys and distributions or lists of parameters to try".

Based on some hyperparameters, the RF model makes a set of decision trees to find the right classification. The value param_distributions is used to determine which of these hyperparameter combinations should be tested.

There is also an explanation here:

[How to correctly implement StratifiedKFold with RandomizedSearchCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51944281/how-to-correctly-implement-stratifiedkfold-with-randomizedsearchcv)